# "Lockable" stickies on the dashboard?

Tags: utilities, dashboard-widget

I'm looking for a dashboard sticky-type widget that I can "lock" so that it won't accept edits. I have a number of stickies that I place there with common terminal commands I use, but I have the nasty habit of hitting `cmd+v` instead of `cmd+c` when I select the command, and `cmd+z` doesn't undo the paste, which means I have to recreate the sticky.

Are there any widgets where I can lock the contents, and maybe even auto copy-to-clipboard on click/select?

Answer (score 4):

I'd like to introduce you to a different approach. I had a similar problem (not the copy/paste error, but that the notes were not really too cool to work with).

This was a long time ago, but since I switched to the free [Notational Velocity](http://notational.net/), I haven't had issues, with the benefit of a very fast (instant) indexing and search in all the trash I want to save :)

Give it a look, it's open source and *very* simple to operate. It may give your Stickies approach some fresh air and you might like it :p